# GCP ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not create directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to install `Datalab` on a `GCP Compute Engine` and running the following:

> **username**@project_id:/home$ datalab create test--zone us-central1-c
>
> Creating the network datalab-network
>
> Creating the firewall rule datalab-network-allow-ssh
>
> Creating the disk test-pd
>
> Creating the repository datalab-notebooks
>
> Creating the instance test
>
> Created
>   [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/**project_id**/zones/us-central1-c/instances/test].
>
> Connecting to test.
>
> This will create an SSH tunnel and may prompt you to create an rsa key
>   pair. To manage these keys, see
>   https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys
>
> Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/
>
> This tool needs to create the directory [/home/**username**/.ssh]
>   before being able to generate SSH keys.
>
> Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not create directory
>   [/home/**username**/.ssh]: Permission denied.
>
> Please verify that you have permissions to write to the parent
>   directory. Connection broken

Anything above you see that is in bold was changed by me for the purpose of this post.  Does anybody have any suggestions for how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted everything and started over about 5 times.  After the 6th time it started working.  Not exactly sure why, but it is no longer an issue for me.

Comment: Consider using `diff` to see what you did differently, or just manually compare the new code to the old code, and see if you can figure it out.  If so, you can come back and edit this answer to include the actual solution.  If not, it probably makes more sense to delete this answer, and then add an EDIT to your question saying what you said here.  (I say this because while it's great that it's working for you now, this does not actually answer the original question.)  Glad it's working though!

Comment: @David McGraw Mark this question as answered